# as3, why does embedded images does memory nomnom after compilation?

Tags: actionscript-3, memory, compilation, embedded-resource

**Situation**
~~~~~~~~
I'm coding an as3 video game and I'm rather surprised when I'm checking the size of my project compared to the compiled swf.

My project size 28 mo.
- assets is 26 Mo
- src is 2 Mo

When I'm compiling it with embedded images, I get 242 Mo swf.
When I'm compiling it without any embedded resource, I get 18 Mo swf.

**Question:**
~~~~~~~~
How can assets simply embedded in a project goes from 26 Mo to (242 - 18 =)224 Mo ?
(I'm looking for a technical answer).

**Notes:**
~~~~~
I don't have any issue whatsoever concerning runtime.
I understand I have to use a loader and not embed big resource in my project, I just want to know why.

Comment: Can you provide a list of asset types? Images (type), sound (type), etc?

Comment: It was only image, and xml, but problem is solved, thanks for your comment :).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps your assets are somehow getting included multiple times. Luckily, there are some tools out there that can help you figure out what's going on:

- In Adobe Flash CC (and similarly in other versions) you can go to `File -> Publish Settings -> Flash (.swf) -> Advanced` and check the box `Generate Size Report`. This will output some text in the output panel on publish that shows you the sizes and categories of everything in your swf.
- Or, you could try the [Visual Size Report](http://labs.adobe.com/technologies/visualsize_report/) add-on. Never tried it myself, so not sure if it's good or not.
- If you're using FlashDevelop, and have a .swf as part of a project, you can see some details about its size. [Here's an example.](http://twitpic.com/4x552f)
- Finally, if you're compiling with flex and mxmlc, you can add the [`-link-report filename`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/flex/using/WS2db454920e96a9e51e63e3d11c0bf69084-7a92.html) option to generate a report that'll help you out.

Comment: thanks for the answer.
helped me to see a stupid thing hidden in Asset file.